# Add iOS icons and launch images under a Resources folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have put all my icons and launch images under a folder called "**Resources**", and I have added all the files into XCode.

When I select the launch images in the XCode by select the file under this folder, it said..

```
a file with name "Default.png" already exists. Do you want to replace it?
```

When I selected yes, and the file "**Default.png**" is being duplicated and place in the project root folder, so now I have two "**Default.png**"

Is it possible to use the file that already in the `Resources` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**iPhone-only applications:**

```
iPhone-only applications may only have one launch image. It should be in PNG format and measure 320 x 480 pixels. Name your launch image file Default.png.

For iPhone 4 high resolution, you can include an additional launch image. It should be in PNG formate and measure 640 x 960 pixels. Name it Default@2x.png. This image will get picked up by the iOS if your app is running on an iPhone 4.
```

**Note:** If your app is not running on an iPhone 4, and you provided both Default.png and Default@2x.png, iOS will automatically pick up Default.png as the launch image.

**Solution** : remove one Default.png place in the project root folder for launch Image

**For ICON**: Refer [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html) link

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same strange behaviour in Xcode. You can just remove the duplicate file in the project root directory. The icons from your Resource folder will be used, because all resources are copied to the app directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default.png that is under your resources folder and delete the one that XCode put under your project root folder. I was asking myself the same question and it is enough to list the names of each of these icons in the Icon files entry in the `Info.plist`.

Everything is in this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html) that Prince mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this dirty hacks:
locate image somewhere on hard drive. then drag it into xcode - select copy if needed.
image was in root and used as icon or launch. then relocate image in finder into folder you want in your project. then go to xcode and select your missing image file. in right sidebar click small icon under location - select current path to you image. now you can also drag you image in the xcode file list.

or
 put image to folder. add them to project. select build phase -> copy bundle resourses.
click + and select you image.

or

put image to folder you want in your project. then simply image to xcode file list - you add this file to project. xcode automate use you image (if it name looks like Default*.png)

result - you image in needed you folder on hard drive and use as icon/launch image

only problem - if you click delete on lauch image form (summary tab). y can't just use you image as launch. you should do all steps from begining

ps: today i faced with this problem - according to apple docs - image should locate in root directory. but if you see in newly created project - apple use the same way - once add image.

hope this help